# python automatically execute __init__ method within class when developing pip library

Tags: python, pip

I am developing a package which is to be uploaded on pypi and to be installed via pip, but I expect it to work with python -m (library name).

It has only one module composed of two classes, one which is to be called like `object = SlaveClass("string")` within the `MasterClass`.
The contents within `__init__` method within `MasterClass` has to operate automatically when the `python -m (libraryname)` is called.

How can I name the class, initial method,...etc?

Answer (score 4):

There's no privileged `main` method in Python like there is in C or Java. Just put the code you want to run at the top level.

```
# beans.py
class Spam:
    def eggs(self, ham):
        print(ham)

s = Spam()  # run Spam's __init__ method
s.eggs("ham")  # run Spam's eggs method
```

Now when you run your module it'll be executed line-by-line from top to bottom. Python will run the `class` declaration statement including the nested `def` (resulting in the creation of a class with a method), then it'll run the two lines of code at the bottom - creating a `Spam` object and running its `__init__` method, and then calling its `eggs` method - likewise.

```
$ python beans.py
ham

$ python -m beans
ham
```

---

Incidentally, Python executes modules from top to bottom when you *import* them, too. Watch:

```
>>> import beans
ham
```

It's common to have code that should *only* run when the module is being *run* (with `python` or `python -m`). The idiom to make this work is by inspecting the current module's `__name__`: every module has a name, which is the package-qualified name of the file if it's being imported, or `"__main__"` if it's being run as the main module.

So we simply put the side-effecting code inside an `if` block.

```
# beans2.py
class Spam:
    def eggs(self, ham):
        print(ham)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Spam()
    s.eggs("ham")
```

Importing it doesn't run the code...

```
>>> import beans2
>>>
```

... but running it as the main module does.

```
$ python beans2.py
ham

$ python -m beans2
ham
```

Comment: What do you think the OP wants? The question wasn't very clear to me so I'd appreciate help deciphering it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Executing modules as scripts"

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/